# Apache CXF: How to secure JAX-RS web service with basic authentication

Tags: java, spring, web-services, cxf, jax-rs

I have a Spring application that publishes some RESTful web services using Apache CXF (using jax-rs). I would like to secure access to those services using HTTP basic authentication. The username and password should be in a Spring configuration file. The main application already uses Spring Security and I would prefer not to mess with that setup.

What is the easiest way to do this? I could write my own ServletFilter but surely there must be a way to configure this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The author of [HTTP Basic Authentication with Apache CXF Revisited](http://chrisdail.com/2008/08/13/http-basic-authentication-with-apache-cxf-revisited/) provides the code of a CXF Interceptor that implements HTTP Basic Authentication validation and a sample of how to define the security interceptor and enable it on a simple endpoint.

Comment: Thanks. I found that one as well. I was hoping for a "few lines of XML" solution but it will do. :)

Comment: Actually, I found another solution here: http://www.mail-archive.com/cxf-user@incubator.apache.org/msg02906.html

Comment: @PascalThivent: How can I send the response body with some key value pair, when a user try to authenticate with bad credentials?